# How can I call method every time in every test when element appears Selenium+Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to ask is it real and useful to make a method which calls every time, in every test when loader (animation) appears and wait that it is disappear. First I think to make a listener + annotation but I can't find info how to do that. I'm new in automation, and ask you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may write a an explicit wait using the :
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element))`

Put this in a method in your base/utility/helper class however you have structured your framework .It will be useful if the loader appears across your tests and application. And you may call this generic method to check if the loader disappears anywhere.

Or further you can also pass the element & timeout itself as an argument and use it for invisibility of any element, that will be even more generic

Comment: I have this explicit wait in my tests (BasePage.java) and use it in other methods.
http://prntscr.com/rxe9dg - example, how I use it
And I want to know, is it possible to realise my idea.